# How can i bind data to child window opened from parent window in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

There is a text box in my parent window. I am opening a new window with window.open(). In that window there is also a text box. I want to bind text boxes to each other with **Angular 2**. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported. You can use use `Window.postMessage()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage to communicate between windows.